Kendo js, issue with position of date on xAxis
I have a chart of (date- value) using Kendo js, the positions were wrong on the xAxis line there's an offset, I used the property  baseUnit: "days", it fixed the first one but still seeing an offset for the others (date-value) and can't fix it ,
here's an image of my chart :

